# The import org.apache.http.client cannot be resolved in eclipce

Tags: java

I have already import the jar httpcore-4.0.1_1 and it still without working. I imported the jar following the next tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRyvnUK2jUg  I am sure that the importing is right, i think the problem is maybe with eclipce because I did the same with another jar and it still without recognize the packages.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;      //Error  The import org.apache.http.client cannot be resolved
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;            //  The import org.apache.http.client cannot be resolved
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;      //  The import org.apache.http.client cannot be resolved



public static void main(String[] args) {
    String server = "www.codejava.net";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "username";
    String pass = "password";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();    //Error FTPClient cannot be resolved to a type

    try {
        // connect and login to the server
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);

        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        System.out.println("Connected");

        String remoteDirPath = "/Upload";
        String localDirPath = "E:/Test/Download/FTP/Test";

        FTPUtil.uploadDirectory(ftpClient, remoteDirPath, localDirPath, "");

        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();

        System.out.println("Disconnected");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add it to the build path?

Comment: Hi @Stigma Rooll, please take a look on this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it will help you to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example about your problem. With this we will be able to help you better.

Comment: this is a MCVE, wrong jar for the intended use..

Answer (score 0):

You got the core installed as it seems, now you need to install the httpclient jar, they are both necessary.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6

Comment: I Did it, now it recognise the packages but the class FTPClient still with the same mistake: FTPClient cannot be resolved.

Comment: Keep going on resolving your dependencies. httpcommons is nicely split in multiple jars, so one can use only what they need. I am afraid you will need to check which jar is which. Important tools are https://mvnrepository.com and others to find jar. You can get clues from the package name.  if this is the lib you want to use, you will need its jar. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Comment: you might be interested in tools like gradle, that help you manege those things.. picking jars is a pretty boring task and doing it so manually will get tedious. Maven, Ivy, Gradle..whichever you pick will help you. a note is that android projects normally use gradle.

Comment: please accept the answer as we fund your issue. if extra help is needed for other issues, it is always better to open another question to not pollute SO.